# Question about asymptotics

Tags: calculus

Let $f(x) > 0$ for all real positive $x$. If $\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} f(x)/x = c > 0$, does this imply that $f(x) \gg x$. That is, is there a constant $c'$ such that $f(x) \geq c'x$ for all real positive $x$?

Comment: My quick guess (because I've got to go out to dinner!) is that if f(x) tends to cx from below, then you've got a counterexample.

Comment: This is not exactly true. For instance, if you set $f(x)=x^2$ on $(0,1]$ and $f(x)=x$ on $[1,+\infty)$. You have $\lim_{+\infty} \frac{f(x)}{x}=1$. But $f(x)\geq c'x$ fails for $x$ small enough, for any $c'>0$. It is true, nevertheless, that there exists $c'>0$ such that, say, $f(x)\geq c'x$ on $[1,+\infty)$. You can replace $1$ by any positive number, but you can't replace the interval by $(0,+\infty)$.

Comment: @Stochastically The problem is not here. The OP did not say $c'=c$. The problem is actually at $0^+$, not $+\infty$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider $f(x)=x^2 |\sin(\frac1x)|,x>0$. Then, $f(x)>0$, and $\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow\infty }\dfrac{f(x)}{x}=\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow\infty }x|\sin(\frac1x)|=1$.
 However, $\nexists c':f(x)\geq c'x,\forall x>0$.

Indeed, $f(\frac{1}{2k\pi})=0, \forall k\in \mathbb N$, and therefore :
$$f(x)\geq c'x\Rightarrow f(\frac{1}{2k\pi})\geq c'\frac{1}{2k\pi}\Rightarrow 0\geq c'\frac{1}{2k\pi}\Rightarrow c'=0$$ which is a contradiction

Comment: Err, but what if $c' < 0$?

Comment: It is supposed that $f(x)>0,\forall x>0$. Therefore if $c'<0$, we have : $f(x)>0>c'x$ ( it is trivial)

Answer (score 1):

The only counter-example I can think of now is a piecewise one:

$$f(x):= \left\{ \begin{array}{ll} -\sqrt{x} & , \mbox{for }x \in [0; 1] \\
x^2 - 2x & , \mbox{for }x \in (1; 3] \\
x & , \mbox{for }x \in (3; +\infty) \end{array} \right.$$

Now, there'll be no $c$ negative, or positve such that the line $y = c'x$ is below the graph. Any line will either cut the graph of the above function, or lie above it.

Hopefully someone else will come up with a nicer solution.

Comment: $f$ is supposed to be positive